# Dynamic update of .py files' variables

Tags: python

I have a python program that loads preferences from another .py file.
And I need to implement a way to update this preferences on the way.

I've been using text files and reading it, and then, use a template, format it, save it and reading again to load the preferences variables. But when I add a new parameter I need to reformat and rewrite the functions that read, format and write.
So I think a better way to do this is with .py files to load. But I don't know if there's a way to modify this variables and save the .py file while using it.

Any idea or solution to this?

Comment: Any sample code snippet where you are trying to load txt file into main python module?

Comment: You don't need code snippets of this, because is what I want to avoid, but, I read the text file and assign variable to every fixed line. I know it's not the better way to this, but, by the time it worked. But, I want to avoid this.